# Weasyprint printing corrupt pdfs

Tags: css, django-templates, windows-10, cairo, weasyprint

I am trying to create a pdf using WeasyPrint on windows 10. It corrupts the css in the generated pdf, as shown in the image below. It is also not able to render images correctly and doesnt open in adobe acrobat with the error: "There was a problem reading this document (135)." (When did the same setup in mac OS a while ago, I did not face these issues)
[image]
I have tried changing the cairo version but that doesnt help. Any ideas on possible reasons why the css is messed up would be helpful. [image]